# npm doesn't work, always throws "cannot find module semver"

Tags: ubuntu, npm, apt-get, ubuntu-19.04

As per title

Tried every solution found here on SO, also tried

`sudo npm apt-get purge npm` -> `sudo apt-get install npm`

`sudo npm reinstall npm`

I'm losing hope, thinking about formatting the whole pc

ubuntu 19.04, npm and node last versions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try with npx

**npx** is a tool included with **npm** as from **version 5.2** that makes it easy to install and run packages.

especially command line tools like create-react-app.
if you need to install a global package that is not installed in your computer
running **npx** will download and execute the package you specified all in one command!

the best part is that **npx** make sure that you always using the latest version of the package without upgrade it each time your about to use it

Comment: -> cannot find module libnpx